# Web crawler: Checking multiple webpages' subpages for a specific string

Tags: python, curl, web-crawler

How would one go about this:
**I have a list that contains approx 160 pages, each with ±5 submenues. In total, I have to check for a specific tag in 800 pages and return the pages where a specific tag is missing.**

I came up with this pseudo-code (thinking in Python) so far

```
for each URL in URL_list
    fetch pagesource
    for each submenu_link in pagesource
        fetch pagesource
        if string "<h2 class=\"subtitle\">" is not in pagesource:
        print submenu_link + "subtitle missing"
```

What do you think? Wrong approach?
Don't know which web crawler lib/module I should use or programming language for that matter - recommendations are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), wich is an easily understable web crawler in pyhton.

I linked the tutorial cause it will make you learn much faster than the doc.
Have fun